# Multiple binary rejection by AppStoreConnect due to launch crash

Tags: ios, crash, app-store-connect

The build has been rejected multiple times from AppStoreConnect with always exactly the same reason

"The app crash on launch"

I've never reproduced the error. I've executed it in every available device and iOS version without success.

In addition, the crash logs that they provided me don't provide too much information.

I've tried to request more information about the environment in which they reproduced the error without success. One time, they said that the crash was in an iPad emulator, but the app works perfectly in every iPad version

Crashlogs **unsymbolicated**:

```
{"app_name":"xxxx","timestamp":"2019-06-20 09:30:05.87 -0700","app_version":"1.4.0","slice_uuid":"d381ff29-a1ec-32a6-af7d-6517137e579f","adam_id":1461455633,"build_version":"1.4.0","bundleID":"xxxx","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)","incident_id":"A985F59F-C669-4A87-9857-4421D1CC164B","name":"xxxx"}
Incident Identifier: A985F59F-C669-4A87-9857-4421D1CC164B
CrashReporter Key:   c71c23eb1e0011687094492985fef3cac2098667
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             xxxx [672]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/0D0670FD-B198-44C2-B537-88709A420EF6/xxxx.app/xxxx
Identifier:          xxxx
Version:             1.4.0 (1.4.0)
AppStoreTools:       10G3
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           xxxx [627]


Date/Time:           2019-06-20 09:30:05.4321 -0700
Launch Time:         2019-06-20 09:30:03.6198 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x236e2f518 0x23600a9f8 0x236d4cec0 0x237817a38 0x23778bf3c 0x100bde604 0x100be1054 0x100bddbb0 0x100bdd7fc 0x100bdd644 0x100c2d370 0x100c627b0 0x262f74020 0x262f75784 0x262f7af10 0x26283f104 0x26284769c 0x26283ed88 0x26283f678 0x26283d9c4 0x26283d68c 0x2628421cc 0x262842fb0 0x262842084 0x262846d84 0x262f79518 0x262b75f0c 0x2397a9d44 0x2397b3754 0x2397b2f5c 0x2368707d4 0x2368155d8 0x2397e40bc 0x2397e3d58 0x2397e4310 0x236dc12bc 0x236dc123c 0x236dc0b24 0x236dbba60 0x236dbb354 0x238fbb79c 0x262f7cb68 0x100ba15ac 0x2368818e0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002369cd0dc 0x2369aa000 + 143580
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000236a46094 0x236a44000 + 8340
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000236926ea8 0x2368cc000 + 372392
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000235ff3788 0x235ff2000 + 6024
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000235ff3934 0x235ff2000 + 6452
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000023600ae00 0x236005000 + 24064
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000235fff838 0x235ff2000 + 55352
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000235fff8c4 0x235ff2000 + 55492
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000002368707e8 0x236810000 + 395240
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000002368155d8 0x236810000 + 21976
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002397e40bc 0x23979e000 + 286908
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002397e3d58 0x23979e000 + 286040
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000002397e4310 0x23979e000 + 287504
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000236dc12bc 0x236d17000 + 697020
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000236dc123c 0x236d17000 + 696892
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000236dc0b24 0x236d17000 + 695076
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000236dbba60 0x236d17000 + 674400
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000236dbb354 0x236d17000 + 672596
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000000238fbb79c 0x238fb1000 + 42908
19  UIKitCore                       0x0000000262f7cb68 0x2626c2000 + 9153384
20  xxxx                            0x0000000100ba15ac 0x100b58000 + 300460
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000002368818e0 0x236880000 + 6368
```

Crashlogs **Symbolicated**:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1251\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1058{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\f0\fs22\lang9\{"app_name":"xxx","timestamp":"2019-06-14 18:12:40.57 -0700","app_version":"1.4.0","slice_uuid":"01ea8f0b-edba-3564-9913-ea253053aa82","adam_id":1461455633,"build_version":"1.3.0","bundleID":"xxx","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)","incident_id":"D2C5D5A1-CE8E-4084-95D6-D9C238F08302","name":"xxx"\}\par
Incident Identifier: D2C5D5A1-CE8E-4084-95D6-D9C238F08302\par
CrashReporter Key:   c71c23eb1e0011687094492985fef3cac2098667\par
Hardware Model:      xxx\par
Process:             xxx [19133]\par
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E8FEC5B1-B7BB-4927-A6EB-ECF1F4DC137C/xxx.app/xxx\par
Identifier:          xxx\par
Version:             1.4.0 (1.4.0)\par
AppStoreTools:       10G3\par
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)\par
Role:                Non UI\par
Parent Process:      launchd [1]\par
Coalition:           xxx [7574]\par
\par
\par
Date/Time:           2019-06-14 18:12:39.9920 -0700\par
Launch Time:         2019-06-14 18:12:35.7129 -0700\par
OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)\par
Baseband Version:    n/a\par
Report Version:      104\par
\par
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)\par
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000\par
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY\par
Triggered by Thread:  0\par
\par
Application Specific Information:\par
abort() called\par
\par
Last Exception Backtrace:\par
0   CoreFoundation                  0x20cd5f518 0x20cc47000 + 1148184
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x20bf3a9f8 0x20bf35000 + 23032
2   CoreFoundation                  0x20cc7cec0 0x20cc47000 + 220864
3   Foundation                      0x20d747a38 0x20d6b1000 + 617016
4   Foundation                      0x20d6bbf3c 0x20d6b1000 + 44860
5   xxx                             0x1002b50e8 -[DataCollector refreshSignal:] + 561384 (DataCollector.m:358)
6   xxx                             0x1002b7b38 -[DataCollector backgroundListenerDataStateChanged:] + 572216 (DataCollector.m:800)
7   xxx                             0x1002b4694 -[DataCollector updateReachability:] + 558740 (DataCollector.m:207)
8   xxx                             0x1002b42e0 -[DataCollector refreshReachability] + 557792 (DataCollector.m:131)
9   xxx                             0x1002b4128 -[DataCollector startCollector] + 557352 (DataCollector.m:108)
10  xxx                             0x100308964 -[MccApi startBackgroundListener] + 903524 (MccApi.m:565)
11  xxx                             0x10033fb24 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1129252 (AppDelegate.m:392)
12  UIKitCore                       0x238ea4020 0x2385f2000 + 9117728
13  UIKitCore                       0x238ea5784 0x2385f2000 + 9123716
14  UIKitCore                       0x238eaaf10 0x2385f2000 + 9146128
15  UIKitCore                       0x23876f104 0x2385f2000 + 1560836
16  UIKitCore                       0x23877769c 0x2385f2000 + 1595036
17  UIKitCore                       0x23876ed88 0x2385f2000 + 1559944
18  UIKitCore                       0x23876f678 0x2385f2000 + 1562232
19  UIKitCore                       0x23876d9c4 0x2385f2000 + 1554884
20  UIKitCore                       0x23876d68c 0x2385f2000 + 1554060
21  UIKitCore                       0x2387721cc 0x2385f2000 + 1573324
22  UIKitCore                       0x238772fb0 0x2385f2000 + 1576880
23  UIKitCore                       0x238772084 0x2385f2000 + 1572996
24  UIKitCore                       0x238776d84 0x2385f2000 + 1592708
25  UIKitCore                       0x238ea9518 0x2385f2000 + 9139480
26  UIKitCore                       0x238aa5f0c 0x2385f2000 + 4931340
27  FrontBoardServices              0x20f6d9d44 0x20f6ce000 + 48452
28  FrontBoardServices              0x20f6e3754 0x20f6ce000 + 87892
29  FrontBoardServices              0x20f6e2f5c 0x20f6ce000 + 85852
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x20c7a07d4 0x20c740000 + 395220
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x20c7455d8 0x20c740000 + 21976
32  FrontBoardServices              0x20f7140bc 0x20f6ce000 + 286908
33  FrontBoardServices              0x20f713d58 0x20f6ce000 + 286040
34  FrontBoardServices              0x20f714310 0x20f6ce000 + 287504
35  CoreFoundation                  0x20ccf12bc 0x20cc47000 + 697020
36  CoreFoundation                  0x20ccf123c 0x20cc47000 + 696892
37  CoreFoundation                  0x20ccf0b24 0x20cc47000 + 695076
38  CoreFoundation                  0x20cceba60 0x20cc47000 + 674400
39  CoreFoundation                  0x20cceb354 0x20cc47000 + 672596
40  GraphicsServices                0x20eeeb79c 0x20eee1000 + 42908
41  UIKitCore                       0x238eacb68 0x2385f2000 + 9153384
42  xxx                             0x1002779f4 main + 309748 (main.m:15)
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x20c7b18e0 0x20c7b0000 + 6368
```

I would like some feedback from you due to I literally don't have more ideas to resolve this situation.

It would be helpful if you would know the solution of the crash having in mind the logs but if you didn't I'm also listening to your next steps suggestions.

Comment: Have you tested the app yourself by doing a clean install from TestFlight?

Comment: At least symbolicate the crash log and update your question with the symbolicated log.

Comment: if you make the buidl to tunesconnect check if there is a error in xcode organizer in buil number

Comment: rmaddy, I tested the builds from TestFlight by doing clean install multiple times and I couldn't reproduce the error.

I've just added the symbolicated logs.

Comment: kjoe, no errors in the organizer in the build number, I checked it

Comment: I was able to reproduce a crash in the launch in iPad emulators, however, it was caused by a known issue of the simulators running with versions older than 9.3.

You can check it in this link (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_1_release_notes)

However, after fix the simulator, I could reproduce the crash never again.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do something with networking on the main thread in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Don’t. Your job here is to return true immediately. Get out of the way and let the app launch.

Comment: Also have you stress tested your app when there is no network? Or a bad network? You can bet Apple does.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, matt.

I executed stress tests without network connection and the app works as expected (No crashes at launch).

About "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions", the app has some initial set checks in that method that are needed before the launch of the app.
The thing is that even, as you say, that method is causing the crash, why I can not reproduce it, as Apple testers do?